# I need to select a ul element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've added an 'Find an online stockist' button to all product pages. If you click on it, it takes you to a different page. I need to set a filter in the page to 'Online Store'. It will look like this when done:
[image]

I'm trying to select this box, so that I can add a

to it. (It's the same box as in the previous screenshot but without any filters in it yet.)

[image]

Please note I can't change the filter box - it's 3rd party code.

When I inspect the page with no filters in it,  it looks like this:
[image]

If I inspect it with a filter, it looks like this:

[image]

I just need to add a new <li> to the 'chosen-choices' but I can't select it.

I can select the store-filter-sec div:

```
var storefiltersec = $(".store-filter-sec");
```

If I view it in the console, it shows the right children:
[image]

But I can't select item 2 - div.chosen-container.chosen-container-multi.

```
var chosenContainer = storefiltersec.find(".chosen-container");
var chosenContainer1 = storefiltersec.find(".chosen-container.chosen-container-multi");
var chosenContainer2 = storefiltersec.find("div.chosen-container.chosen-container-multi");
var chosenContainer3 = $(".chosen-container");
var chosenContainer4 = $(".chosen-container.chosen-container-multi");
var chosenContainer5 = $("div.chosen-container.chosen-container-multi");
var chosenContainer6 = $(".chosen-container .chosen-container-multi");
```

```
The plan is that once I can get hold of div.chosen-container.chosen-container-multi, I can then get to 
ul.chosen-choices (one of its children):
```

[image]

I tried to get chosen-choices by tag.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('ul');
```

'chosen-choices' shows up in the console:

[image]

but I can specify just that one. I tried this:

```
console.log('specific element', elements[12]);
```

and get:

[image]

Please tell me how I can select ul.chosen-choices in either javascript or jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in javascript to select .store-filter-sec and to put it in a variable:

```js
const el_filtersec = document.querySelector('.store-filter-sec');
```

Now from this selected element you select .chosen-container

```js
const chosen-container = document.querySelector('.chosen-container');
```

by the way you can select directly chosen-container

Now the problem is you have several, so:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.chosen-container')).forEach(el => {
   // do what you have to do...
}
```

If you still want store-filter-sec and for each finding chosen-container:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.store-filter-sec')).forEach(el1 => {
   Array.from(el1.querySelectorAll('.chosen-container')).forEach(el2 => {
   // do what you have to do...
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but still can't get hold of .chosen container:var byqs = document.querySelector('.store-filter-sec');
 
 console.log('byqs', byqs);
 
 
 var myContainer = document.querySelector('.chosen-container');
 
 console.log('myContainer', myContainer); It works fine for .store-filter-sec but myContainer is null when I view it in the console.

Comment: Is it a question of timing? Content chosen-container coming from server? and function fire before it's in DOM?

Comment: Yes, I switched from $(document).ready(function(){}) to window.addEventListener('load', function({}) and I can select chosen-container.  Thank you so much.